Advice improving DIY rear wheel trueing stand?
I am an amateur tinkerer and usually true my wheels directly on the bike using the brakes mostly (flit it or lift it somehow).
This time I have bought new wheels and decided to build a trueing stand from old parts for the old wheels:



QUESTION: I am not sure how to implement the dishing or reference needles, any advice? is it a good idea to try and build it in the stand as opposed to creating a separate attachment?
Details:
The board is a piece of kitchenboard from a built in fridge, so it's quite thick, stiff and flat. The gears are from an working but consumed shimano cassette, so they are reasonably flat. The pressure from the wheels fastener together with the rear hub connected to the gears keep the hub quite fix in place and perpendicular, there is absolutely no flex I can feel with the hands. Tightening the hub fastener actually reduces the spinning of the wheel gradually, so maybe I am pressing on something I shouldn't, but maybe it's also a nice feature to exploit.
The drawn circles were drawn like a compass, using a drill and the perforated metal plate, so they were quite centered, but the hole has been enlarged for the hub after the process, so it may be bit a bit off center; either way they are meant just for reference to center the rim roughly before truig and new more centered lines can be drawn if necessary.
The wooden pegs are for convenience, so that the stand can be layed flat (and protect the floor from damage if it falls on its back) or vertical and turned 180 degrees if needed.
The metal plate on the other side is just to give the wheel fastener something stiff and flat to press on instead of just the wood, there is also a washed between the bolt and the plate because the hole in the plate is 10mm, which gives some clearance to the axle to stick out if the hub is too long.
I also have some cut out of the rim size in thick cardboard that I can gue or attach for spacing and referencing.


I don't have a comprehensive answer, so I'll just comment: I replaced both of my hubs over the past year, and built a truing stand out of a board and two wooden uprights. I have woodworking tools so I was able to square everything up, but ultimately it was not stiff enough for the job. The slightest flex meant too much movement at the rim. It was useful to get the wheel roughly into shape, but for the final few mm of adjustment, I put the bike upside down and used the frame as the reference. One of these works surprisingly well: www.aliexpress.com/item/1005005099629098.html

In order to check for the centering of the rim, I would install the wheel one way, then flip it around and see if the rim was still in the same place.

yes, the flex is what kept me from even thinking of using wooden boards squared together, but this thing has no flex whatsoever that I can feel, which gives me hope, the applied tension is what gives the perpendicular alignment, the nails keeping the gears in place are just to not have them loose when the wheel is off

I have used old forks as the truing stand before. Drill a 25.4mm hole in your worktop and stick them in. You could open up a set for the rear wheel or saw the rear triangle off an old frame and bolt it down to your workbench.

and then what do you use to "measure" for the actual truing? I just feel like if I can put two dishing points on the stand, or even 6 or 8 reference points, like a dishing arrangement with 8 arms, it could save a lot of time in turning and looking. I've thought of drilling some screws along the blue circle and measure the exposure of the tip with a micrometer, but it feels very rough and it's difficult to get them concentric

My concern with your current setup is that you're assuming the cassette is perfectly concentric and coaxial with the rim, which is not necessarily the case in real life (if you've ever seen a cassette slowly wobbling around as the wheel freewheels...) Conventional truing stands ensure the wheel is true with respect to the frame/fork (helpful), whereas yours ensures it's true wrt the cassette (not as helpful). It would be good to double check the wheel using your old method once you've reinstalled it on the bike.

@MaplePanda I had completely forgot about the wobbling and was indeed assuming what you say. On the other hand I am not using the cassette per se, but I opened it up, removed the pins and the plastic spacers and checked the gears themselves are flat. I see no reason why the cassette itself would be wobbly, so the wobble must be in the cassette slot of the hub (which sounds like a problem), or am I still missing something?

If there is a good way to check the rim using the stand then the same method should be able to check for hub wobble (naked, without rim and spokes, sigh) and see if the idea is flawed from the start. Maybe the wobble is the reason I feel the rolling resistance?
